# Qlikview how to get all excluded values on qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I have two columns on Qlikview table: date and full name.
All people work on some dates.

If I choose a date, it shows me a list of people who work on that date.
I need to make a table of all the people that **do not** work on that date.

I have tried to make a page trigger to select unchecked but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Where are the codes....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Select the date you want -> Right click on the date's list box and do 'select excluded'

Comment: i need it to be as a report so it does work but not what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use element function E() which represent the excluded set.

```
sum({$<Dim1 = E({$})>} Expression1)
```

In your case Dim1 would be the Date dimension.

//Micke

Answer (score 0):

Click on the date you want.

Right click on it.

Select Excluded.